# How to turn 9V DC to 300V DC?

Tags: capacitor, boost

I recently acquired a capacitor from an old power supply - 400V 120uF. I want to be able to charge it, preferably without being connected to mains. I'd like to do this with a 9V battery (or any other kind of battery that works). Finally, I want to be able to charge it to a voltage that its safely rated for, i.e. anything in the 300-350 Volt range.

I'm quite a beginner when it comes to electrical engineering, so my research may not be particularly good, but from what I understand the simplest way to accomplish this is to use a boost (step-up) converter. I find it difficult to interpret their voltage ratings for Vin and Vout.

For example, will the [XL6009 module](https://www.nikom.biz/pdf/XL6009.pdf), which has an input voltage rated between 3.6V and 36V, with a duty cycle of 95%, allow me to hook up a 9V battery as input and safely get 180V output?

Alternatively, is there another method for accomplishing this boosting of DC voltage?

Comment: Is there any particular reason _why_ you want to charge it up to 350 V? That may be enough energy to kill you if you touch it.

Comment: Google the flash units out of disposable cameras. These should do precisely what you want. They tend to use a ‘ringing choke’ inverter consisting of a little transformer, a transistor and some R and C.

Comment: There is nothing safe about this circuit no matter how sophisticated the charger is. 300 volts can easily push 30 mA through the body and, as conduction drop s due to skin damage that current could rise within a fraction of a second to a lethal level. To get 300 mA requires a load (your body) of 10 kohm. The CR time of 10 kohm and 120 uF is over 1 second. That means you could receive a lethal current for several hundred milliseconds. It is not safe.

Comment: .5 C V^2 says 7.35J.  Imagine a kg mass with a needle on the bottom hung 0.75 m above you by a horse's hair and be careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **photo flash charging circuit** can do that job. You could harvest one from an old camera, or build it yourself. It’s a popular project.

And there’s an IC or that: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXSC440.pdf

Another: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/lt3420-charges-photoflash-capacitors-quickly-and-efficiently.html

Still another: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva330/slva330.pdf

Treat these circuits with respect. The voltage and power they can deliver are potentially lethal.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely understand that this sort of voltage and capacitance is where capacitors start becoming lethal. I will exercise great care with this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the datasheet of the [XL6009](https://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf) itself (not the modules), the maximum voltage one can achieve is 60V. So you can't use them to charge the capacitor (at least not with only one of them, it might be possible with several modules with independent batteries).

The easiest solution would be using mains (a diode + a resistor would be enough). If you don't want to use mains, then look for a boost/step-up converter with output voltage in the 300-350V range (not sure how easy they will be to find), or a power supply with outputs in the same range.

But according to what you wrote, I would advise you NOT to play with capacitors charged to 350V : if when not connected to mains, you might get quite some electrical shock from a capacitor charged at high voltage (the usual recomendation when disassembling power supplies is to keep them unpluged for several days before opening them, to let time for this big capacitor to discharge)